# Set up rEFInd to boot Ubuntu directly (no Grub menu displayed)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, refind

I would like to set up a menuentry in rEFInd to boot directly into Ubuntu, without using GRUB. I would like to keep Grub on hand, however, with a menu entry for that.

I've copied the most recent kernel and refind_linux.conf from `/boot/` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`, and created the following refind.conf:

```
#
# refind.conf
# Configuration file for the rEFInd boot menu
#

timeout 0
screensaver 300
banner mybanner.png
banner_scale fillscreen
scanfor manual,external,optical

menuentry Ubuntu {
    loader /EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.19.0-31-generic.efi.signed
    icon /EFI/refind/icons/os_linux.png
    ostype linux
    options "root=UUID=92f926f7-19f8-4a2b-9e9a-bf91db475a3c ro initrd=boot\initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic"
    initrd boot\initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic
}

menuentry Grub {
    loader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
    icon /EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_unknown.png
}
```

The menuentry for Grub works great, but the menuentry for ubuntu so far only <strike>creates kernel panic (blinking capslock key, no boot) with and without the ostype and options.</strike>  By adding initrd lines, it now just says that it cannot find initrd..., tries again higher up, and dies.

Ideally, I'd also like rEFInd to automatically update the ubuntu entry when the kernel gets upgraded.

As I mentioned, I'm keeping GRUB as well, so I'd be ok with passing control to grub transparently, but I couldn't figure out how to send options directly to grub if that's the recommended way of doing this.

Comment: I do not yet use rEFInd. But you are missing the initrd line. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html Example there is Arch, so be sure to use Ubuntu's version.

Comment: Yes, just fixed that. Still not working, but I will update the question after the next reboot.

Comment: I would think path has to be same as kernel's path, but not boot without leading / no matter what.

Comment: It seems that everything is relative to /boot/efi (as shown in Ubuntu). I can't figure out how to access anything above that. /../ didn't seem to work, and no combination of /, \, and boot seemed to work either. For the time being I'm not going to do menuentries and just change the icons so I can tell other people which one to choose.

Comment: Many of use use grub to directly boot links in / or /vmlinux and /initrd.img. Those should be equivalent to Arch example, I think. Do not know details on Arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have reasons for not using rEFInd's auto-detection that you've not mentioned, you're going about this the wrong way. Namely, you should rely on auto-detection for both the GRUB and direct-boot options. A default install with default options should definitely pick up GRUB automatically. This would be equivalent to your `menuentry Grub` option, except that the description and icon shown by rEFInd would be different. (You can easily change the icon in a number of ways, as described [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#icons).)

Depending on where your kernel is and how you installed rEFInd, your kernels might or might not be auto-detected. If not, the usual solution is to install an EFI filesystem driver for whatever filesystem holds your kernel. Drivers for ext2/3fs, ext4fs, ReiserFS, Btrfs, and a few on which your kernels will likely not appear all ship with rEFInd; and drivers for lots more come in the [efifs package.](http://efi.akeo.ie/) Drop the appropriate driver in the `drivers` or `drivers_x64` subdirectory of your rEFInd installation directory and rEFInd should be able to detect your kernels in their normal location. (Note that rEFInd 0.10.0 made some changes that help when using Btrfs; with earlier versions, you had to add `@/boot` to the `also_scan_dirs` line in `refind.conf` to detect kernels on Btrfs volumes. This is no longer necessary with rEFInd 0.10.0.)

Using auto-detection has some big advantages over what you're trying to do:

- There's no need to manually copy your kernel; rEFInd should detect them from their normal "homes."
- When you upgrade your kernel, rEFInd will auto-detect the newly-installed version with no need for re-copying the kernel or updating your configuration file.
- It's easier. In most cases, auto-detection "just works," or works with minimal extra configuration. (You may need to run `mkrlconf` in Ubuntu to get the right kernel options to be used in some cases.) The manual `initrd=` option can be finicky (non-obvious typos and simple mistakes often wreak havoc), but auto-detection of the initrd file is typically flawless on Ubuntu systems.

The biggest disadvantage to auto-detection is that you can't control the name displayed as a prompt for the kernel. IMHO, this is a small price to pay for the advantages.

If you insist on doing it the way you're trying, the problem you're having is caused by the fact that, unless I've missed something, you've copied the kernel, but not the initrd file, to the ESP. The easiest way to get it to work is to copy *both* files to the same location. You must then specify the initrd file using the same path you use to refer to the kernel. For instance:

```
menuentry Ubuntu {
    loader /EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.19.0-31-generic.efi.signed
    icon /EFI/refind/icons/os_linux.png
    ostype linux
    options "root=UUID=92f926f7-19f8-4a2b-9e9a-bf91db475a3c ro"
    initrd /EFI/ubuntu/initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic
}
```

Note that you should identify the initrd file *either* on the `options` line *or* on a separate `initrd` line, not both. (It would *probably* work with redundant specifications, but I can't guarantee that. At best, it could lead to confusion and/or extra work when you need to modify the settings.)

Comment: I was actually focusing on the names, and figured listing each in a menu entry was the best way to go about it.  It seems there is no easy way to do this, so I've put on custom icons (which I could edit to include the names) and left it at that. After realizing that every kernel update would mean manual reconfiguration, that really pushed it over the edge for me.

Comment: My follow up question is **how do I access something ABOVE the /EFI/ folder?** My kernels are all in /boot/, which rEFInd can only see things in /boot/efi/. I had to copy the kernels to a folder within /EFI/ to even find them.

Comment: By default, rEFInd scans (on every partition) the root directory, the `boot` directory, and most subdirectories of `EFI`. Thus, rEFInd should detect your kernels once it's got the right filesystem driver, since Linux distributions normally put kernels in `/boot`, which will be either the root directory or `boot`, depending on whether or not you've got a separate `/boot` partition. You can change this default by editing the `also_scan_dirs` option in `refind.conf`. If it's not working now, you may have done this inappropriately or you may be missing the right filesystem driver.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that since they appeared to linux as /boot/, they would be such to rEFInd. Actually, I have a separate partition, so that would explain why it wouldn't find them.

Comment: If they're in a separate `/boot` partition, then they should be scanned by default, since they're in the `/boot` partition's root directory. If they're not appearing, then most likely either you've altered the `also_scan_dirs` line in `refind.conf` or you don't have an appropriate filesystem driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To solve it I took the ext4.efi driver/file and put it in the drivers folder under the rEFInd directory. That solved the issue for me.