# Want rEFInd to boot into grub after selecting Linux from rEFInd

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, refind

I saw, of course, the extensive documentation on Rod Smith's website, and understood most of it, and have searched online [Set up rEFInd to boot Ubuntu directly (no Grub menu displayed)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697407/set-up-refind-to-boot-ubuntu-directly-no-grub-menu-displayed) etc but can't seem to be sure on what to do.

My multiboot macbook pro retina has rEFInd installed "manually from OSX" and rEFInd works great. When I select a Linux from the rEFInd menu I want it to go to Grub though.

On all my Linux OSs/partitions, they each have their respective boot loader grub(2) on the partition with them. I can clearly see the ESP partition (`/dev/sda1` or `/dev/disk0s1`) under Linux's `/boot/efi/...`

I've noted that under one of the Linux's, `/etc/default/grub`, has `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` so I'm not sure if grub is being used or not, as I don't see it...

Thanks and hope this is clear...

Comment: May we know the reason why you want an additional layer of bootloaders, knowing that rEFInd already does the job and so does UEFI? Knowing your goal with such complexity someone may have suggestions.

Comment: I happen to simply find grub menu easier to work with when editing or adding boot options. I also wouldn't mind maybe looking into booting a different linux when I get there...

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Unfortunately I know nothing about rEFInd or Macs but Rod Smith belongs to this community and I've seem one of his (beautifully brilliant) answers recently so, with some luck, he may see your question and come to the rescue.

Comment: And +1 because this is interesting and potentially challenging.

Comment: Just came across another reason... One Linux doesn't boot into kernel I want and without grub menu I don't know which number to set default to, e.g. with grub-set-default. Guess I could guess with grub.cfg, but still...

Comment: +1 - I just ran into exactly the same question. In addition, I use a "good-old" ext4 boot partition with a zfs-enabled grub + initrd to boot into a root-on-zfs setup. Somehow that doesn't work, probably because refind doesn't pick up the proper boot arguments.

Comment: FWIW, the actual question is probably "how to select the MBR bootloader from refind".